# mvc 5 does not delete a cookie

Tags: cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to delete all cookies from the responder,
the function is inside a service project.

code:

```
int limit = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    cookieName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[i].Name;     
    aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    aCookie.Value = null;
    aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)                
}
```

but the response only adds more cookies with the same name.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
{
  Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```

Edit: this suggestion is based on the guestimate that it has to do with you adding the cookie to the response instead of updating the one that's already present.

Comment: tnx for the comment, It worked the first time I ran the app, but when I ran it again it added the same number of cookies with the same names so everytime I am trying to delete and add a cookie it multiplies the number of cookie

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of head banging I finaly noticed that while creating the cookie as followed it did the trick

```
cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName, CustId);
```

declaring the cookie in any other manner didn't work,
for example :

```
 int limit = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
            {
                cookieName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[i].Name;     
                aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
                aCookie.Value = null;
                aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);              
            }
```

or

```
 var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[CookieName];            
            if(cookie == null)
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName, CustId);
             }
            else
            {
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                //HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
            }
```